# Call to JenkinsAPI(https) just hangs

Tags: python, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, jenkins-api

My code is given below

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins

def get_server_instance():
    jenkins_url = 'https://<privateJenkinsServer>:<port>'
    print "Hello" 
   server = Jenkins(jenkins_url, username = 'foouser', password = 'foopassword')
    return server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_server_instance().version
```

When I execute this, it just prints *"Hello"* and then hangs. What could be the reason for this ?

N.B. I am running this in my corporate network behind a proxy.

Reference: http://pythonhosted.org/jenkinsapi/using_jenkinsapi.html#example-1-get-version-of-jenkins

When I killed the command, I get the following error.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 643, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
```

Complete log.

```
>>> execfile('C:\Users\idatta\Project\Python\Demo\JenkinsAPI_v1.py')
started
https://jenkm1.discoverfinancial.com:8443

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('C:\Users\idatta\Project\Python\Demo\JenkinsAPI_v1.py')
  File "C:\Users\idatta\Project\Python\Demo\JenkinsAPI_v1.py", line 28, in <module>
    print get_server_instance().version
  File "C:\Users\idatta\Project\Python\Demo\JenkinsAPI_v1.py", line 19, in get_server_instance
    server = Jenkins(jenkins_url, username = 'idatta', password = 'Gr33nCard_1', ssl_verify=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi\jenkins.py", line 59, in __init__
    JenkinsBase.__init__(self, baseurl, poll=not lazy)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi\jenkinsbase.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.poll()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi\jenkinsbase.py", line 61, in poll
    data['jobs'] = self.resolve_job_folders(data['jobs'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi\jenkinsbase.py", line 100, in resolve_job_folders
    jobs += self.process_job_folder(job, self.baseurl)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi\jenkinsbase.py", line 112, in process_job_folder
    result += self.process_job_folder(job, folder_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi\jenkinsbase.py", line 112, in process_job_folder
    result += self.process_job_folder(job, folder_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi\jenkinsbase.py", line 107, in process_job_folder
    tree='jobs[name,color]')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi\jenkinsbase.py", line 79, in get_data
    response = requester.get_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi\utils\requester.py", line 109, in get_url
    return requests.get(self._update_url_scheme(url), **requestKwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 756, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 643, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

Comment: I also tried downloading certificates from my org's Jenkins home page. But still I am getting SSL error.
cafile = 'C:\Users\idatta\Project\certs\Verisign.cer' 
server = Jenkins(jenkins_url, username = 'uid', password = 'pwd', ssl_verify=cafile)    
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)

Answer (score 3):

The error on `v = self._sslobj.read(len)` implies you interrupted while read was in progress. It seems to be completely undocumented, but jenkinsapi tries to download information on every job when it starts and if your Jenkins repo is huge it's gonna take forever. It's possible to set lazy=True but it will still try to load all the jobs when you try to access a single job. Probably better to use some other library.

```
server = Jenkins(jenkins_url, username = 'foouser', password = 'foopassword', lazy=True)
```