# Jenkins Library hangs when try to get jobs through python Jenkins Library

Tags: python, jenkins, jobs, freeze

I'm building a python script that retrieve some information about Jenkins with the Python library Jenkins, so originally, when I retrieve all jobs, the library works well, and the script run wonderful. But today, when I try to retrieve some job, or all jobs, my script stay hung forever trying to retrieve the Job. What could be happening?

```py
import jenkins
jen = jenkins.Jenkins(url='<URL>', username="<USERNAME>", password="
<TOKEN>")
jen._session.verify=False
allElements = jen.get_all_jobs()
```

Launching on python console, I got it hung at these point, with these output.:

```py
>>> jen.get_job_info("deployer")
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:857: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
```

REFERENCE: I saw these question: [Call to JenkinsAPI(https) just hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010989/call-to-jenkinsapihttps-just-hangs)
but the different part is that my script log-in successfully, it hangs at the retrieve time.
Thank you!